# Hibernate генерация таблиц

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

При генерации таблиц в intellIj 2016.3 классы создаются следующим образом:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "mir", schema = "ipm", catalog = "ipm")
public class Mir {
    private long entityId;
    private Long fileseq;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    public long getEntityId() {
        return entityId;
    }

    public void setEntityId(long entityId) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
    }
        @Basic
    @Column(name = "FILESEQ", nullable = true)
    public Long getFileseq() {
        return fileseq;
    }

    public void setFileseq(Long fileseq) {
        this.fileseq = fileseq;
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы таблицы генерировались так:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mir", schema = "ipm", catalog = "ipm")
public class Mir {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    public long ENTITY_ID;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FILESEQ", nullable = true)
    public Long FILESEQ;

}
```

без геттеров и сеттеров? (не спрашивайте почему)

Можно ли как нибудь сделать так? 
если нет, то можно ли сделать так, чтобы нижнее подчеркивание в названии колонки не удалялось? не `getEntityId()`, а `getEntity_Id()` хотя бы?

Comment: Второй вариант будет работать, только что проверил. Дополните лучше какой IDE пользуетесь для генерации гет/сет, т.к. Intellij IDEA генерирует такой гет: `long getENTITY_ID()`

Comment: Попробуй lombok

Comment: Вопрос про сферического коня в вакууме - ОООЧЕНЬ мало информации. 1. Делая поля класса `public` вы нарушаете один из принципов ООП - инкапсуляция.
2. Называя методы `getEntity_Id()` вы нарушаете Java конвенцию (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Уверен, для Вашей задачи есть более элегантное решение. P.S. Не в JSON, случайно, мапите в `entity_id`? :)

Comment: Геттеры и сеттеры нужны для чтения и записи базы.
Без них он выдаст ошибку, что не может считать с базы или записать туда

Comment: да знаю все это я прекрасно. 
нет, не json, но мне нужно обрабатывать json (и не только) данные, где  было бы легче получаться поле класса по названию, как, например, в json пришло бы. поэтому и написал не спрашивайте почему так делаю.

Comment: @sae В Guava есть все необходимое для решения Вашей задачи "правильно": CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, "SomeInput");

Просто переводите имя поля из одного представления в другое.

Comment: @MrFylypenko `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 Ultimate` с плагином гаибернейт

Comment: IDEA нормально создает гет/сет, в соответствии с Java конвенцией, и если в названии поля объекта есть нижнее подчеркивание, то оно будет и в гет/сет. Скорее всего Вы преобразуете данные из JSON  в JAVA объект, то используйте готовые библиотеки для этого (напр. FasterXML), для них гет/сет не проблема, чем использование public полей.

Comment: @MrFylypenko нет, я генерирую сущности из MYsql базы. полагин для гибернейта сама так генерит, как в первом варианте.

Answer (score 1):

1. Делая поля класса `public` вы нарушаете один из принципов ООП - инкапсуляция.
2. Называя методы `getEntity_Id()` вы нарушаете Java конвенцию (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

В Guava есть все необходимое для решения Вашей задачи "правильно":

`CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE, "SomeInput");`

Просто переводите имя поля из одного представления в другое.

Comment: да знаю все это я прекрасно. 
нет, не json, но мне нужно обрабатывать json (и не только) данные, где  было бы легче получаться поле класса по названию, как, например, в json пришло бы. поэтому и написал не спрашивайте почему так делаю.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте почитать про библиотеку lombok. Она может генерировать код на лету,  всякие геттеры, сеттеры, конструкторы, equals'ы , hashcode'ы.

Должно получится что-то примерно такое:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "mir", schema = "ipm", catalog = "ipm")
public class Mir {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
    private long ENTITY_ID;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FILESEQ", nullable = true)
    private Long FILESEQ;

}
```

Так же нужно включить поддержку этой библотеки в вашей IDE, в нетбинсе ставится галочка в настройках проекта.  В Idea, нужно качать плагин.

Comment: это классная штука, когда все с нуля пишешь или когда рефакторишь автоматически, но! 
у мня все классы уже сгенерированы, и рефакторинг удаляет все аннотации, нет времени для всех классов, методов и полей руками дописывать.